# Android dialog not resizing properly

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-dialog

I have a dialog for setting a new password for a login in my Android app. As part of it, it displays an error message at the top depending on the validity of the new password and the confirmation. There are two possible messages, both of which take up two lines onscreen:

```
<string name="warning_minimum_password_length">New password must be at least %d characters long.</string>
<string name="warning_unmatched_passwords">The two passwords must be the same.</string>
```

When I set the message to the `warning_minimum_password_length`, the dialog properly resizes to allow room for the message to be two lines. But when I set the message to the `warning_unmatched_passwords`, the dialog only allows room for one line (unless it was previously set to the other message, in which case it keeps the correct height).

Here is the code for setting the messages:

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                String newErr;
                // Check passwords meet rules
                if (txtNewPwd.length() < MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH)
                {
                    txtError.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), a.getString(R.string.warning_minimum_password_length), MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH));
                    btChangePwd.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else if (!(txtNewPwd.getText().toString().startsWith(txtConfirmPwd.getText().toString())))
                {
                    txtError.setText(a.getString(R.string.warning_unmatched_passwords));
                    btChangePwd.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    txtError.setText(null);
                    btChangePwd.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        };
        txtNewPwd.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        txtConfirmPwd.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

And here is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.baus_systems.inventorycount.MainActivity">

    <!-- Login progress -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_login_error"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        tools:text="Login Errors" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/account_login_form"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtNewPwd"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="8"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_new_password"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtConfirmPwd"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_confirm_password"
                    android:imeActionId="6"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt_change_pwd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in_short" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_cancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txt_bt_cancel" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have tried a few different ways to get this to work properly, including:

1. Setting the Layout height to `WRAP_CONTENT` after setting the error messages
2. Setting the message to the one that resizes properly immediately before the one that doesn't, including:

   a.  putting a Thread.wait between the two messages, which crashes the app.

   b.  putting an Invalidate between the two messages, which has no effect.

Is there any reason why this should be properly resizing on one error message but not the other? How can I get this to resize properly?

Comment: Set maxLines to 2 in xml and see if there is any change.

Comment: @mTak: No effect.

Comment: Can you post all the layout?

Comment: @mTak: Updated.

Comment: From the way you coded the TextWatcher it seems impossible to get 1st the warning_unmatched_passwords. It seems that always the 1st error that will appear will be warning_minimum_password_length, and as you mentioned after that the text displays fine. So in which case does warning_unmatched_passwords show first?

Comment: @mTak: Fill in the required number of characters in the `txtNewPwd`, and the error will clear. After that, deleting characters there will show the `warning_minimum_password_length` as expected, or typing other letters than expected in the `txtConfirmPwd` will show the `warning_unmatched_passwords` with only one line. (It might be worth noting that deleting characters from the `txtNewPwd` at this point will show the `warning_minimum_password_length` error with only one line, pushing the issue onto that message.)

Comment: So the problem arises for both strings. One more try: in the else statement replace txtError.setText(null); with txtError.setText("");

Comment: @mTak: This does nothing either. And to clarify, the `warning_minimum_password_length` is only affected if it immediately follows the `warning_unmatched_passwords`. If it immediately follows no message, it is fine. Only the message after no message affects whether it will resize properly.

Comment: It's a strange behavior. So try strange workarounds. I wonder what would happen if you added txtError.setText(null); before txtError.setText(...); for both strings in if and 1st else.

Comment: @mTak: That doesn't seem to help either. It looks like explicitly calling `setLines(2)` works, though. I just hope I don't have to worry about it changing how many lines it needs on different devices or something.

Answer (score 0):

This may be just an issue with the dialog layout not being refreshed. I also had a similar issue and calling `invalidate` alone didn't help. Instead of invalidating the text view (or maybe in addition to it) you can try the following:

```
txtError.getParent().requestLayout();
```

As for the reason 'why', I don't know. The texts are different in that the first one is only a template that needs to be filled with some value. Because the value isn't known at first and could be arbitrarily large (thus potentially taking even more than two lines), maybe the system automatically performs an additional layout pass on the whole dialog. Since the other text's length *is* known, the system could be 'optimizing' and only redrawing the text view itself.